# How to bring a form in the top of desktop?

Tags: winforms

I want to pop up a form in C# .net 2.0 which should be in front of the desktop (topmost) until the user clicks the close button.

How to do so?

I tried the code from here: 
http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/fenster-wirklich-in-den-vordergrund-des-desktops-bringen-SID1005.aspx

But it didn't work.
My system is Win7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the form's TopMost property to true and MinimizeBox property to false.

Answer (score 3):

Code below will create MessageBox with TopMost property making it on Top until user clicks No or Yes.

```
       DialogResult result = DialogResult.No;
        try {
            result = MessageBox.Show(new Form {
                                                  TopMost = true, MinimizeBox = false,
                                              }, "some text", "some topic", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        } finally {
            if (result == DialogResult.No) {

            }
        }
```